# Add GrailsParameterMap to PostMethod or convert it to NameValuePair

Tags: grails, groovy, httpclient

I have GrailsParameterMap and i wants to pass this params to PostMethod.

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    PostMethod method = new PostMethod(SIGNUP_API_URL);
    method.addParameter(params)
    try {
     int returnCode  = client.executeMethod(method); 
    }
```

Can Anyone tell me how to do it by passing GrailsParameterMap directly to postmethod.

Your help is appriciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Removed `java-api` tag as that doesn't even make sense as a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
params.each { key, value ->
    method.addParameter( key, value )
}
```

Comment: True ;-) Changed it :) Not sure if it will be the required solution or not though... Hard to tell from the Q what is desired

Comment: thanks... it works, in my params value is of type list also, so i needed to check the value is instance of String then add this. thanks and sorry for tagging this question for java-api